# Javascript for iOS: Elastic Scrolling without disabling all Scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll

I want to do two things:

1. Disable Elastic Scrolling of document
2. Enable scrolling of `div.master`

I know you can disable the elastic scrolling using the following:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) { e.preventDefault() },false);
```

However this disables all scrolling, not just the elastic scrolling. I thought maybe that you could just enable scrolling again for just the `div.master` but I'm not sure how you would do that.

[image: I want just this section to scroll]

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no built-in solutions. You will need to create your own algorithm or download a pre-made one. Or are you already using a library?

Answer (score 1):

Disable your page’s default scrolling with:

```
document.body.ontouchmove = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

or

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

and enable scrolling with some CSS:

```
.scrolling {
   overflow: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

To completely remove elastic scrolling you’ll have to wrap the scrolling div inside another scrolling div like that:

```
<div class="scrolling">
  <div class="scrolling">
    // Your content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer does not work in IOS7

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have absolutely no idea, but [iScroll](http://www.cubiq.org/iscroll) does it. For a better version of iScroll, use [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4/).

Oh yeah, and after checking out AnonyMouse, I advise do not use `position: fixed;`, because only iOS 5 supports it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will have to completely block the default page scroll on IOS using preventDefault() and then mimic the behavior without the bounce. As mentioned above, iscroll does this, but it's a bit bloat and cumbersome when you compare it to other libraries such as [Zynga Scroller](https://github.com/zynga/scroller)

You could have more fun trying to build your own as well:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/